# Problem with corrupted MariaDB database file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When the MariaDB database on my Docker container keeps restarting itself, I figured out that the problem is in my database (I think it's corrupted).

```
root@website:~# docker-compose ps
      Name                     Command                 State                    Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
root_mariadb_1      docker-entrypoint.sh mariadbd    Restarting
root_phpmyadmin_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh apac ...   Up           0.0.0.0:9500->80/tcp,:::9500->80/t
                                                                  cp
root_redis_1        /opt/bitnami/scripts/redis ...   Restarting
```

MariaDB docker container error logs file:

```
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.7.3+maria~focal started.
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.7.3+maria~focal started.
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.7.3-MariaDB-1:10.7.3+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=16587504,22296402
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CREATE, FILE_DELETE or FILE_MODIFY before FILE_CHECKPOINT for tablespace 60
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:01 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:01 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:01 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[0m 2022-07-27 23:22:01 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - '/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
```

I already have a full physical backup of my MariaDB database and I have already restored it to my local/dev/test environment.

When I start MariaDB on localhost (xampp), the problem still persists (like on my docker container).

Here is MariaDB error logs from localhost/xampp:

```
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16777216, chunk size = 16777216
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=16587504,22296402
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CREATE, FILE_DELETE or FILE_MODIFY before FILE_CHECKPOINT for tablespace 60
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
2022-07-29 11:04:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-07-29 11:04:21 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-07-29 11:04:21 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-07-29 11:04:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-07-29 11:04:21 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-07-29 11:04:21 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

File and folder on MariaDB:

```
root@website:/data/mysql# ls -l
total 206316
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  18268160 Jul 29 05:29 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump        52 Jul 29 05:29 aria_log_control
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     16384 Jul 25 16:27 ddl_recovery-backup.log
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       872 Apr 10 01:34 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  79691776 Jul 25 16:27 ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump 100663296 Jul 25 16:27 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  12582912 Jul 25 16:27 ibtmp1
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump         0 Apr 10 01:27 multi-master.info
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      4096 Apr 10 01:27 mysql
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump        14 Apr 10 01:27 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      4096 May 28 05:44 websitedb
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump      4096 Apr 10 01:27 performance_schema
drwx------ 2 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     12288 Apr 10 01:27 sys
```

My database file on websitedb:

```
root@website:/data/mysql/websitedb# ls -l
total 13404
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     2094 Apr 10 02:00 slide.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    98304 Jul 25 16:27 slide.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump       67 Apr 10 01:58 db.opt
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     4630 Apr 10 02:00 role.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   114688 Jul 25 16:27 role.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump     7505 Apr 10 02:00 setting.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    98304 Jul 25 16:27 setting.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump    10307 Apr 10 02:00 user.frm
-rw-rw---- 1 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump   212992 Jul 25 16:27 user.ibd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [MDEV-28870](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28870) fixed in 10.7.5.

Physical backups can preserve some forms of corruption. So if your backup is generating this then:

- use `--innodb_force_recovery=6` as a container
- take a logical dump of the database in the container
- restore into a 10.7.5+ container.

Comment: I got error when dump sql dataabase using mysqldump.

mysqldump: Got error: 1030: "Got error 194 "Tablespace is missing for a table" from storage engine InnoDB" when using LOCK TABLES

After using --skip-lock-tables

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table `gpservices`': Got error 194 "Tablespace is missing for a table" from storage engine InnoDB (1030)

Comment: I'm sorry it. It looks like its corrupted then. Reading the MDEV there are gaps that might make this recoverable, maybe a backup restoration without a prepare stage, but I'm going into very unfamiliar territory even suggesting this.

Comment: Thank you, the problem solved when I dump mysql per table.