# MariaDB 11.1.2-GA on Windows 11 Pro crashes every couple of days, sometimes couple of hours

Tags: mariadb, windows-11

Is there any **current** (October 2023) solution for MariaDB 11.1.2-GA on Windows 11 Pro crashing every couple of days or even sometimes every couple of hours with the following error in .err log:

```
InnoDB: Missing FILE_CREATE, FILE_DELETE or FILE_MODIFY before FILE_CHECKPOINT
```

I am asking for *current* report on this problem (or solution the best), because [every report](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/315009/35230) that I [have found](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28870) says that [this is an old bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31410) that was supposedly resolved [long time ago](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28976). Which turns out to be not true.

Every DBA question, JIRA ticket or blog entry says that this was fixed in 10.7.5 and yet it happens in 11.1.2-GA again. And I can't find any report on any kind of regression. Of course, I cannot find any solution as well, hence this question.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Setting `innodb_force_recovery` on any value ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61744085/1469208) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43247919/1469208) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/318218/35230)) doesn't work and still causes `mysqld` to quit with the above error
2. Deleting *ib_logfile0* ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61187808/1469208) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/322902/35230)) doesn't work. MariaDB dies with error that this file is missing instead of recreating it, as said
3. [Setting `innodb_log_file_size = 48M`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39091569/1469208) doesn't help. I already had it said to this value. I didn't [tried to set it to `1000M`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48577605/1469208), but that sounds like an overkill.
4. [Setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556491/1469208) doesn't work as well. I already had it said to this value

[Deleting my corrupted files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/320759/35230) is the only solution that I have found working:

1. Rename *c:\[path]\data* into *c:\[path]\data2*
2. Execute `mysqld` (usually dies, but recreates files in *c:\[path]\data*)
3. Overwrite all files in *c:\[path]\data2* with recreated copies from *c:\[path]\data*
4. Delete *c:\[path]\data*
5. Rename *c:\[path]\data2* into *c:\[path]\data*
6. Execute `mysqld`

At this points MariaDB starts and stops normally, but of course the entire dataset is **not** correct, because such bluntly performed copy process isn't any backup-restore process at all. Everything must be recreated manually, i.e.:

- Access to phpMyAdmin, including all it's tables and settings
- All users, passwords, privileges using PMA
- All data tables by SQL import

Usually takes an hour or two. And then, after couple of hours or days at most, data gets corrupted again, and the whole story starts from the beginning.

This is my private laptop, my dev environment. I am the only person using it and PHP running my application is the only process writing to MariaDB. So by no mean we can say anything about some race conditions that are mentioned in MariaDB's JIRA tickets.

Comment: The error appears to be happening during crash recovery; perhaps it might be helpful to find (and possibly eliminate) the reason of the crash that _leads_ to the database needing recovery in the first place. Did you do any investigation in that direction?

Comment: I suggest creating a [new bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org). Your restore process means its repeatable and It needs to be investigated why. Do downvote the wrong misleading errors you came across

Comment: @mustaccio The database crashes during its restart only. Since the only environment that shutdowns regularly (and where db is started up often) is my dev environment, for test purposes I allowed myself to not turn off the database / system / computer at all, but to keep it running "for ages". No problem so far. From database perspective an application that I am developing is extremely simple. It is treated by the app as a simple set of Excel tables. A regular CRUD operations on seven tables, happening not more than 2-3 times per minute. So extra configuration, no stressful usage, nothing.

Comment: @danblack Will do so as this certain looks like some kind of regression.